# enclosure fabrication resources for the upscale hobbysist

Tags: audio, enclosure

I recently saw a beautifully made 1RU 8Ch microphone pre-amp that was in a beautiful enclosure with a  very pro looking faceplate and so on. The engineer
wouldn't share who made it for semi-obvious reasons.  This was the only pic I could find. Does anyone know where you can go for pro looking enclosures that don't completely break the piggy bank?
[image]

Comment: Anyone with a CNC router should be able to do this. Best to go local if you can or you can mail order from somebody like front panel express.

Comment: Some of the PCB companies do this as the PCB drilling and milling equipment is capable of milling aluminium. See [Panel-Pool](http://www.panel-pool.com/) in Europe, for example. (I have no connection with the company.)

Comment: It's not uncommon for the hardware to cost more than the electronics, so sometimes the answer is "use the wallet crowbar" if you desire the look.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a friend of mine, a freelance electronic engineer making the enclosures for his designs.
He mostly uses off the shelf aluminium enclosures which he customizes with the following method.

He uses a cnc mill to engrave his company logo and various labels that go with the components on the panel like the "clip" in your image. He then uses black nail polish to fill the engraved words. When the nail polish has dried he uses a flat piece of PE or PTFE (whatever is nearest his hand at the moment) to scrape the excess paint off the surface leaving the engraved words intact.

The result could not be better and looks just like the enclosures in your image.
As for the cost, it doesn't cost him nothing because he own the cnc mill so I don't know if it will be expensive to have someone mill it for you..

Another way of performing the engraving if by etching away part of the aluminium. I have done if by using the toner transfer method to cover everything on the surface except the parts I want engraved. I then submerged the piece of aluminium in ferric chloride which ate away the uncovered metal pretty quickly. I then proceeded to paint and scrape it with black nail polish.

The latter method produced an inferior result especially when there are straight lines involved but it's dirt cheap and you can do it at home.

Comment: You could also screen print (or stencil) the markings, then etch to lower the rest of the panel, resulting in raised painted markings.